# Faster processing alternative to a for loop

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I am using a `for` loop to replace the values in `xen.biomart$chromosome_name` (column 3) that match with `chr.alias.biomart$ensembl`, with the value on `chr.alias.biomart$ucsc` on the same `chr.alias.biomart` row.
It works, but it takes too long to long to process (+20 min).
Is there any faster alternative?

```
for(i in 1:nrow(xen.biomart)){
  for(x in 1:nrow(chr.alias.biomart)){
    xen.biomart[i,3][xen.biomart[i,3] == chr.alias.biomart$ensembl[x]] <- chr.alias.biomart$ucsc[x]
  }}
```

The `xen.biomart` has 146816 rows and `chr.alias.biomart` has 46 rows with the references of values that I want to replace.

```
> head(xen.biomart[,3])
[1] "MT" "MT" "MT" "MT" "MT" "MT"

> head(chr.alias.biomart)
  ensembl  ucsc assembly    genbank      refseq
1       1  chr1     Chr1 CM004443.2 NC_030677.2
2      10 chr10    Chr10 CM004452.2 NC_030686.2
3       2  chr2     Chr2 CM004444.2 NC_030678.2
4       3  chr3     Chr3 CM004445.2 NC_030679.2
5       4  chr4     Chr4 CM004446.2 NC_030680.2
6       5  chr5     Chr5 CM004447.2 NC_030681.2

> dput(xen.biomart[c(1,1000,10000,15000), ])
structure(list(ensembl_gene_id = c("ENSXETG00000034356", "ENSXETG00000034782", 
"ENSXETG00000029203", "ENSXETG00000021054"), external_gene_name = c("", 
"", "xtr-mir-144", "cdk2ap2"), chromosome_name = c("MT", "1", 
"2", "3"), start_position = c(1L, 122943147L, 34088294L, 148518850L
), end_position = c(68L, 122971793L, 34088355L, 148548901L), 
    description = c("", "", "xtr-mir-144 [Source:miRBase;Acc:MI0004938]", 
    "claudin 15, 1 [Source:Xenbase;Acc:XB-GENE-994817]")), row.names = c(1L, 
1000L, 10000L, 15000L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(chr.alias.biomart[c(1:10,46),])
structure(list(ensembl = c("1", "10", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "MT"), ucsc = c("chr1", "chr10", "chr2", "chr3", 
"chr4", "chr5", "chr6", "chr7", "chr8", "chr9", "chrM"), assembly = c("Chr1", 
"Chr10", "Chr2", "Chr3", "Chr4", "Chr5", "Chr6", "Chr7", "Chr8", 
"Chr9", "MT"), genbank = c("CM004443.2", "CM004452.2", "CM004444.2", 
"CM004445.2", "CM004446.2", "CM004447.2", "CM004448.2", "CM004449.2", 
"CM004450.2", "CM004451.2", "MT"), refseq = c("NC_030677.2", 
"NC_030686.2", "NC_030678.2", "NC_030679.2", "NC_030680.2", "NC_030681.2", 
"NC_030682.2", "NC_030683.2", "NC_030684.2", "NC_030685.2", "NC_006839.1"
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 46L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You can almost certainly do this without recourse to any loops at all: R is, after all, vectorised by default.  A small sample of test data will enable us to provide concrete examples.

Comment: The easiest way to share sample data is `dput()`. `dput(xen.biomart[1:5, ])` will give a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows of `xen.biomart`. Do that for both relevant datasets to give us sample data. Pick just a few rows of each that illustrate the problem. And feel free to drop unneeded columns as well.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks! I edited to add that information

Comment: Thanks for the sample data. Looking at your code, it seems like you're comparing the 3rd column of `xen.biomart`, which is `chromosome_name` and in your sample data only has the value `"MT"`, with `chr.alias.biomart$ensembl` which has integer values `1, 10, 2, 3, 4` and looking for matches. There aren't any matches ("MT" isn't an integer) so nothing happens. Could you please confirm what columns are being compared, make sure you're choosing an appropriate sample of data to illustrate the problem (your sample should show some matches!), and also show the desired output? ....

Comment: I think this is a simple `match` or `join` operation, but the example you've shared doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: A detailed description in words would also help. Instead of "replace values in a column based on 2 columns in another data frame" something like "replace the values in the `xen.biomart$chromsome_name` column with values from the `chr.alias.biomart$ucsc` column whenever there is a match between `xen.biomart$chromsome_name` and the `chr.alias.biomart$ensembl` column would be a lot clearer.

Comment: @GregorThomas sorry for being unclear.
the `xen.biomart$chromosome_name` has thousands of repeating values and all values have a correspondent on `chr.alias.biomart$ensembl`, it just happened that the first examples were all `"MT"`. The code works perfectly as I wanted to. My problem is that it takes way longer than I think it should, and I assumed there could be a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: There is a much more efficient way. But I can't test it and show it to you without something to test on. That's why I'm asking for sample data that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @GregorThomas I updated the samples, and changed the description. I hope I made it more clear. Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1):

This should be much faster. If you need more speed, use the `data.table` package.

```
library(dplyr)
xen.biomart = xen.biomart %>%
  ## join the relevant alias column into xen biomart
  left_join(
    select(chr.alias.biomart, ensembl, ucsc),
    by = c("chromosome_name" = "ensembl")
  ) %>%
  ## replace all chromosome_names with ucsc value (if not NA)
  mutate(chromosome_name = coalesce(ucsc, chromosome_name)) %>%
  ## drop ucsc columns
  select(-ucsc)
#      ensembl_gene_id external_gene_name chromosome_name start_position end_position
# 1 ENSXETG00000034356                               chrM              1           68
# 2 ENSXETG00000034782                               chr1      122943147    122971793
# 3 ENSXETG00000029203        xtr-mir-144            chr2       34088294     34088355
# 4 ENSXETG00000021054            cdk2ap2            chr3      148518850    148548901
#                                         description
# 1                                                  
# 2                                                  
# 3        xtr-mir-144 [Source:miRBase;Acc:MI0004938]
# 4 claudin 15, 1 [Source:Xenbase;Acc:XB-GENE-994817]
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked almost instantly, compared to many minutes of processing with the loop! I appreciate your help!